# Why is "to" used in "climate scientists TO issue stark warning"?

Tags: to-infinitive, headlinese

> World’s climate scientists **to** issue stark warning over global heating threat

In this sentence why there is “to” before verb “issue”? Is there any grammatical rule about this usage of “to” ?

Comment: In the future, please link the source of the text you have questions about. This is not a sentence, it's a news headline. Headlines follow a particular set of rules that are designed to save space. In headlines, infinitives mean that the thing hasn't happened yet, but is going to occur--in this case, as the article states, the report will be issued on Monday. https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/aug/08/worlds-climate-scientists-to-issue-stark-warning-over-global-heating-threat

Comment: Thank you so much. I will.

Comment: Exactly what Katy said. The "to" used in headlines is really a shorthand way of saying "going to..." or "planning to..." or similar.

Comment: Also, news headlines are pretty vague. It's extremely doubtful that all the climate scientists in the whole world agree on anything and would speak in unison.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the comments...

Headlines have a different set of rules since they want to save space. In this case, "to" is just an abbreviation of "going to" or "planning to".